# Tomcat: how to change location of manager and host-manager to a subdirectory

Tags: linux, tomcat

I'm running a Tomcat 6.0.28 at port 8080 in a Debian Squeeze box. I'm a newbie in tomcat.

I would like to change the location of manager and host-manager applications. That is, instead of going to:

http://myserver:8080/manager/html

I would like that to be:

http://myserver:8080/somesubdirectory/manager/html

Is this possible?
If yes, how can I achieve this?
I would really appreciate any help in this.

I've been trying to change the context of /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml from /manager to /somesubdirectory/manager with no success. Also I tried to create a symlink under /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/somesubdirectory/manager with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop Tomcat.
2. Empty the work directory.
3. Rename
   $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/manager to
   $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/somesubdirectory#manager
4. Start Tomcat.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment and look for "Multi-level contexts" for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to change Tomcat's **/manager** to **/hello123**

1. > sudo mv $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/manager $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/hello123
2. update **docBase** in */etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml*, points to above /hello123
3. > sudo mv manager.xml hello123.xml
4. > sudo service restrat tomcat

Done. Refer to this article [how to change Tomcat manager webapp path](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-manager-default-path/) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

Do this (from now on, I assume we're in the tomcat root directory) :

1. Copy the webapps/manager directory to webapps/somesubdirectory
2. Open the webapps/somesubdirectory/WEB-INF/web.xml file with a text editor
3. To every "url-pattern" occurrence, add the "/manager" string. So for example, this:
   `<url-pattern>/html/*</url-pattern>` becomes this: `<url-pattern>/manager/html/*</url-pattern>`.
   Save the file.
4. Restart tomcat

Comment: Thanks Lacek. I did that and restarted tomcat but if I try to go to http://myserver:8080/somesubdirectory/manager/html this error appears: Status HTTP 404 - /subdirectory/manager/html is not available.

Answer (score 0):

With Tomcat 9 (on Ubuntu/Debian) just go to the path `/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost` and rename the `manager.xml`.

e.g. rename it to:

- `manager2.xml` for `http://example.com/manager2`
- `subdir#manager.xml`for `http://example.com/subdir/manager`

cf. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming for the naming rules